# trigger and procedure issue in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, procedures

I want to run a specific script(named proc.php file see below) when the system is inserting new record to one my db tables.(i read about that i need for this the UDF lib, i already installed this on my server and it`s working properly)

For this i wrote a trigger and a procedure

Trigger code:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `db_name`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trigger`$$

CREATE /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */ TRIGGER `trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `billing` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    CALL `db_name`.`udf_proc`(NEW.user_id);
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

procedure code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/ PROCEDURE `db_name`.`udf_proc`(userId INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
    DECLARE result CHAR(255);

    SET cmd = CONCAT('php -f "/var/www/html/proj/proc.php" ',userId);
    SET result = sys_eval(cmd);
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

when i am trying to insert a new record manually nothing happens, and i don`t know why

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain, that MySQL has permissions for `/var/www/html/proj/proc.php` and for running php scripts ?

Did you checked MySQL logs ?

```
/var/logs/mysql.log
/var/logs/mysql.err
```

Comment: I saw an error message "Could not open input file"
/var/www/html.../proc.php123
I think there need to be a space between the proc.php to 123?
How can i edit the trigger to add that space?

Comment: Remove trigger by `DROP TRIGGER` and create it one more time:)

Comment: I drop the current trigger and then create the same trigger with out the drop trigger line, in alter option i can see the drop down command agian